# Fitting a Sphere to 3D Points

Tags: python

I have a problem. I must write a code which fit the best sphere to a list of noisy points.
I tried to use least squere method but the result which I got is not accurate.
My question is: what is wrong with this code?
Maybe i should use other method to solve this problem?

```
import math
import numpy as np

ret = []

def kulaSrednio(spX, spY, spZ):
    spX = np.array(spX)
    spY = np.array(spY)
    spZ = np.array(spZ)
    A = np.zeros((len(spX), 4))
    A[:, 0] = spX * 2
    A[:, 1] = spY * 2
    A[:, 2] = spZ * 2
    A[:, 3] = 1

    f = np.zeros((len(spX), 1))
    f[:, 0] = (spX * spX) + (spY * spY) + (spZ * spZ)
    C, residules, rank, singval = np.linalg.lstsq(A, f)

    t = (C[0] * C[0]) + (C[1] * C[1]) + (C[2] * C[2]) + C[3]
    radius = math.sqrt(t)
    ret.append(C[0])
    ret.append(C[1])
    ret.append(C[2])
    ret.append(radius)
    return ret
```

Comment: What metric are you using?

Comment: (That is, given two spheres, what formula determines which one is a better fit?)

Answer (score -1):

There is a pretty simple analytic solution to your problem. Recall the [sphere equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere), e.g. in 3D:

`(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2 + (z - z_0)^2 = r^2`,

where `(x_0, y_0, z_0)` is the center of the sphere. Given a set of points we can derive the optimal `r^2` for the sum of the Euclidean distances for each of your points denoted by `i`.

`L = \sum_i^n (\bar{x}_i^2 + \bar{x}_i^2 + \bar{x}_i^2 + r^2)^2`,

where the bar indicates we have centered coordinates, we basically subtracted the mean. The next thing to do is to set the derivative of `\frac{dL}{dr^2} = 0` and solve for `r^2`. You can do the derivations yourself. The final result is the following:

`r_{opt}^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i^n \bar{x}_i^2 + \bar{x}_i^2 + \bar{x}_i^2`.

Here is an example in 2D:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# simple 2D example with 3 points
X = np.array([[0,1],[1.5,1.5],[2,0]])
center = X.mean(0)
X_centered = X - center
r_opt = np.sum(X_centered**2)/len(X_centered)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))
ax.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1])
ax.scatter(center[0],center[1],color='r')
shpere = plt.Circle((center[0],center[1]),np.sqrt(r_opt),fill=False,color='r')
ax.add_artist(shpere)
ax.set_xlim((center[0]-r_opt*1.1,center[0]+r_opt*1.1))
ax.set_ylim((center[1]-r_opt*1.1,center[1]+r_opt*1.1))
```

[image]

Red dot is the center, blue dots are your noisy measurements and the red circle is the fitted sphere. The example is 2D for visualization purposes, but the results generalizes to three or more dimensions. Sorry for not being able to use any MathJax, maybe this post would fit better in [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: That fits an isotropic Gaussian function, not a sphere. It’s not necessarily going to do what you want. Consider a point cloud made up of randomly distributed points having `x•x = r`, but with  the x coordinate skewing  positive. The resultant sphere will not have the right radius or center.